# Setting up Kafka cluster with 3 Zookeeper and 3 Broker node

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

On setting up Kafka cluster with 3 Zookeeper and 3 Broker node, only one of the broker node starts and remaining two doesn't. Cluster is present in the same host.on running the command for other two broker they just start for a second and then closes.

The error log message is-

```
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,874] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x3004e189c730000, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,877] WARN Exception when following the leader (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:84)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:85)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:118)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.readPacket(Learner.java:158)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:92)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1253)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,966] INFO shutdown called (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
java.lang.Exception: shutdown Follower
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.shutdown(Follower.java:201)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1257)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO Shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO Shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FollowerRequestProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO Shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO FollowerRequestProcessor exited loop! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FollowerRequestProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,967] INFO CommitProcessor exited loop! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,972] INFO shutdown of request processor complete (org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,983] INFO Shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:12,983] INFO SyncRequestProcessor exited! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,040] WARN PeerState set to LOOKING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,040] INFO LOOKING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,041] INFO New election. My id =  3, proposed zxid=0xa00000037 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,041] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0xa00000037 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0xa (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,042] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0xa00000037 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0xa (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,043] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x900000011 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0xa (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,044] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0xa00000037 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0xa (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,245] INFO LEADING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,248] INFO TCP NoDelay set to: true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,248] INFO zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshots = 10 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,248] INFO zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshotTimeout = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,249] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 4000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,249] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,249] INFO Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /u01/data05/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir /u01/data05/zookeeper/version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,250] INFO LEADING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 5 MS (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,251] INFO Snapshotting: 0xa00000037 to /u01/data05/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.a00000037 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,861] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0xa00000037 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0xa (n.peerEPoch), LEADING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,877] INFO Follower sid: 2 : info : server:12888:13888:participant (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,902] INFO On disk txn sync enabled with snapshotSizeFactor 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,902] INFO Synchronizing with Follower sid: 2 maxCommittedLog=0xa00000037 minCommittedLog=0x600000041 lastProcessedZxid=0xa00000037 peerLastZxid=0xa00000037 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,902] INFO Sending DIFF zxid=0xa00000037 for peer sid: 2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,924] INFO Have quorum of supporters, sids: [ [2, 3],[2, 3] ]; starting up and setting last processed zxid: 0xb00000000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,928] INFO Configuring CommitProcessor with 2 worker threads. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor)
[2021-02-02 20:19:13,932] INFO Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ContainerManager)
[2021-02-02 20:19:14,248] INFO Follower sid: 1 : info : server:2888:3888:participant (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:14,259] INFO On disk txn sync enabled with snapshotSizeFactor 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-02-02 20:19:14,259] INFO Synchronizing with Follower sid: 1 maxCommittedLog=0xa00000037 minCommittedLog=0x600000041 lastProcessedZxid=0xb00000000 peerLastZxid=0xa00000037 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:14,259] INFO Using committedLog for peer sid: 1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
[2021-02-02 20:19:14,259] INFO Sending DIFF zxid=0xa00000037 for peer sid: 1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the configuration you're using for each broker?

Comment: You don't need (and shouldnt use) 3 zookeepers on the same host. There's also no benefit of doing the same for the brokers

Comment: I wanted to do a poc on same host will it not work?